# Why the CSS of a vanilla JS project getting overwritten by React JS compiler?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a vanilla JS project which I tried to implement in react. The HTML/JSX of both are same and also the stylesheet are same only difference being the entire html for vanilla JS being written in a single **index.html** file

```
<body>
    <header>
      <h1>Todo app</h1>
    </header>
    <form>
      <input type="text" class="todo-input" />
      <button class="todo-button" type="submit">
        <i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="select">
        <select name="todos" class="filter-todo">
          <option value="all">All</option>
          <option value="completed">Completed</option>
          <option value="uncompleted">Uncompleted</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </form>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
  </body>
```

and for React JS they are distributed into two files the **App.JS**

```
import React from "react";
import './App.css';
//importing components
import Form from "./components/Form";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header>
          <h1>Todo app</h1>
      </header>
      <Form />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and a *component* file **Form.js**

```
import React from "react";


const Form = () =>{

    return(
        <form>
            <input type="text" className="todo-input" />
            <button className="todo-button" type="submit">
                <i className="fas fa-plus-square"></i>
            </button>
            <div className="select">
                <select name="todos" className="filter-todo">
                    <option value="all">All</option>
                    <option value="completed">Completed</option>
                    <option value="uncompleted">Uncompleted</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </form>
    );
}

export default Form;
```

The relevant **CSS portion**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #f6d365 0%, #fda085 100%);
  color: white;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
header {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

header,
form {
  min-height: 20vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
form input,
form button {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  border: none;
  background: white;
}
form button {
  color: #ff6f47;
  background: #f7fffe;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
form button:hover {
  background: #ff6f47;
  color: white;
}
```

However, the React output seems to override the CSS
[image: ReactJS Output]

and doesn't interpret the CSS as in a html file for the vanilla project
[image: Expected Output]

Please help me out to understand this strange behavior of React compiler.

Comment: It is not really clear exactly what your problem is. React does not change the way HTML and CSS works.

Comment: but the CSS has been differently interpreted as you can see the styling has been stricken down leaving a distorted output.

Comment: This could be due to a number of issues. Your CSS might be competing with other CSS files. Your toolchain may not be properly including the CSS in the produced file. You could be using a non functional CSS importer.

Comment: how to debug and find that out? there is no other CSS file so no competing I guess. How to determine on the other two?

Comment: Looks like you're loading Bootstrap (a mostly CSS framework) in the React build but not in the vanilla build. This could be because you've included it only in your react build, or because it's failing to load in your vanilla build, or something else.

Comment: @Ouroborus thanks! Write this as a separate comment and I will mark it as an accepted answer. It seems the fontawesome icon I used suggested me to include certain links in **index.html** head that includes bootstrap and causes the clash. In the vanilla project no bootstrap links are used.

Comment: @code-mon I also get the same problem , but I did not add any bootstrap links. Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: Bootstrap included in one build but not the other was the cause of the difference.

From my comment on the question:

> Looks like you're loading Bootstrap (a mostly CSS framework) in the React build but not in the vanilla build. This could be because you've included it only in your react build, or because it's failing to load in your vanilla build, or something else.

And asker's response:

> It seems the fontawesome icon I used suggested me to include certain links in index.html head that includes bootstrap and causes the clash. In the vanilla project no bootstrap links are used.